# MySQL add index on relatively big table (InnoDB)

Tags: php, mysql, database, rdbms

I have a relatively big InnoDB table (~20m rows) and I want to add an index to a column.

The table is being read from and written to frequently, so I want the table to still be usable while the index is being added.

How can I achieve this?

I currently see two options:

- Just blindly add the index and pray nothing will happen
- Creating a replica table with the structures + the index, add the data from the original table and then rename the replica to the original and dropping the original.

Is there a better way?

Thanks :)

MySQL version: 5.0.51

Comment: I think second option will be much better as you will be having backup of your huge data.

Comment: with frequent writes the second approach is going to probabky cause some concurrency issues. cross your fingers and just add the index

Comment: before you add the index you might want to test on a copy on another machine based the comments here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: This also might speed things up http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/06/improved-innodb-fast-index-creation/

Comment: you can build a slave and master make the change in the slave reverse roles

Comment: i would test and just see which would suck less

Answer (score 2):

2nd option would be great but how can you achieve this? I recommend [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)